# How to require a class file in Rails 3 /lib directory from another class in /lib

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby and Rails and am having trouble getting a class in /lib to reference another class in /lib.

I have this in my application.rb file, as I understand Rails 3 does not auto-load the lib directory:

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Then I have lib/Rec.rb

```
class Rec
  Movie @movie
...
```

and then lib/Movie.rb.  I am able to instantiate a Movie object in a controller, but referencing in Rec produces:

```
undefined method `Movie' for Rec:Class
...
lib/rec.rb:2:in `<class:Rec>'
lib/rec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is...messed up. What do you mean `Movie @movie`? What exactly do you want to do?

That piece of code is invalid Ruby unless you have declared `Movie` as a method somewhere. But Movie should be a class, right? So that's the first reason Rails is not loading your `movie.rb` file, because Ruby is confused about what your code means.

Maybe what you mean is

```
@movie = Movie.new
```

Something like that should autoload your `movie.rb`, because now the code makes sense.

But..

```
Movie @movie
```

..doesn't mean anything..

Comment: Your assessment is correct, my syntax was causing the issue.  As I mentioned I am new to Ruby and this issue was due to my habit of specifying a type in statically-typed languages.